# Genitiv form of "voller"

Tags: genitive

I found a usage of Genitiv but I can't explain to myself why there is that form. The sentence is

> Unsere Schränke und Schubladen sind voller Sachen.

I assume this is a direct translation of *"Our cabinets and drawers are full of things."* As I know so far Genitiv is either between two nouns or after "Präposition" like "wegen", "laut". Genitiv here is a little strange to me because it is between a noun and "sein" verb.

I guess because of "full of" meaning, the case of "Sachen" here is Genitiv. Could someone help me confirm this explanation? Could you also give me other examples of other adjective beside "voll"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use any other adjectives in this construction. You cannot even say that something is "leerer Dinge" to mean "it is empty".

Also, the notion that this is an adjective at all poses problems. You can say "voller Haß" to mean "full of hatred", but if 'voller' were an adjective, the inflection wouldn't add up ('Haß' is masculine, which doesn't fit the ending -er as a genitive).

Therefore it is more useful to think of 'voller' as one of the rare prepositions that take the genitive, rather than a special genitive expression. It may have originated as such a construction, but its present-day behaviour doesn't fit that definition.

Comment: Thanks Kilian for your answer, especially the hint to view "voller" as preposition instead of derivation from adj "voll". From your hint, I went on to find out that there is an entry for "voller" in the dictionary: https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=voller and also in duden https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/voller. Great thanks! I will edit the question to match this finding.